# Why does my UWP App highlight where the mouse is hovering by default?

Tags: uwp, desktop-application

I don't want the elements in my app to appear with any highlighting when hovered by the user as it does below:

[image: Highlighting Bad]

```
<ListView>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Padding="25,25,25,25" FontWeight="SemiBold">Inputs</TextBlock>
    <GridView>
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Padding="25,25,25,25">Your Team:</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox ></ComboBox>
    </GridView>
</ListView>
```

The ListView is just that in the Inputs.xaml

I have tried to edit those colors for the hover effects in the App.xaml but with no impact made as below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush" Color="Magenta" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush" Color="SpringGreen" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Orange" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush" Color="Blue" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="LimeGreen" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush" Color="ForestGreen" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush" Color="DodgerBlue"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Cyan" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Purple" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="DarkTurquoise" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush" Color="DarkGray" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Do you mean to use Grid or StackPanel instead of GridView? That's easier than turning off Reveal Highlights. Changing styles for ListViewItem of course has no effects on GridViewItem.

Comment: Can I use a StackPanel with two "columns"?  I need to be able to have a text prompt ("Your Team:") and then a combobox that the user can select a team next to it.  So those would be on the same "row".  Essentially I'm trying to build a form that the users can input some data into.

Comment: <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

Answer (score 0):

> > Why does my UWP App highlight where the mouse is hovering by default?

Since you are using ListView and GridView, they both set different appearances of their items in the `PointerOver` state or selected state, ect. If you want to cancel any highlight when hovered by the user, you need to change the styles of ListView and GridView. In the default style of ListView and GridView, when trigger the PointerOver state, their `PointerOverBackground` property and `RevealBorderThickness` property will take effect. So you could change their value in Application.Resources. For example:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent"/>
        <Thickness x:Key="ListViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GridViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent"/>
        <Thickness x:Key="GridViewItemRevealBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

However, the ListView and GridView still have the selected state, if you do not want to select any items of them, you could set `SelectionMode` of them as `None`.

**In addition**, as TimTim Wong said, it's better to use StackPanel instead of ListView or GridView to layout controls, they are usually used to display a collection. StackPanel does not have such states, you can use it directly. For example:

.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock FontSize="30" Padding="25,25,25,25" FontWeight="SemiBold">Inputs</TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock FontSize="24" Padding="25,25,25,25">Your Team:</TextBlock>
        <ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Center"></ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```